C header files show "red error line" in VS Code
It compiles correctly with gcc command line, but .h files show these red error lines.
The files (.c and .h) are in the same folder.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Windows 11.
#ifndef PONTO_H
#define PONTO_H

typedef struct ponto Ponto;

Ponto* ponto_criar(float x, float y);
void ponto_liberar(Ponto* p);

int ponto_acessar(Ponto* p, float* x, float* y);
int ponto_atribuir(Ponto* p, float x, float y);

float ponto_distancia(Ponto* p1, Ponto* p2);

#endif // PONTO_H



VSCode is finicky to set up. Any slight deviation from the official set up process may result in strange errors. Use a different IDE if you can, otherwise wipe off everything and reinstall according to this.

From what you have shown, it would appear that VSCode is not recognising .h files as C/C++ headers. You could try fixing the file association as described at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview.

@OldBoy if struct and #ifndef are marked, it is unlikely that this is caused by any headers.

Thanks, @OldBoy! I clicked on 'Select Language Mode' at the bottom right corner in VSCode, then 'Configure File Association for .h' and chose 'C'. I closed and reopened VSCode, and now it's working. It was set for "dasm" file.

@Gerhardh Well obviously it was, as shown by OP's answer above.
